# Google cloud function onCreate not writing to the Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a google function for firebase that when A new conversation is added the function attaches it to the Users table under a new collection for each user in the conversation but when the function gets triggered nothing happens in the database, So far I have console logged the values tp make sure they ware being set right and they ware I have also tried looking at the google function logs and there are no errors according to the logs the script ran with no errors

Here is the code for the function

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const onConversationCreated = functions.firestore.document("Conversations/{conversationID}").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    let data = snapshot.data();
    let conversationID = context.params.conversationID;

    if(data){
        let members = data.members;
        for(let index = 0; index < members.length; index++){
            let currentUserID = members[index];
            let remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u: string) => u !== currentUserID)
            remainingUserIDs.forEach((m: string) =>  {
                return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(m).get().then((_doc) => {
                    let userData = _doc.data();
                    if(userData){
                        return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(currentUserID).collection("Conversations").doc(m).create({
                            "conversationID": conversationID,
                            "image": userData.image,
                            "unseenCount": 1,
                        });
                    }
                    return null;
                }).catch(() => {return null})
            });
        }
    }
    return null;
});
```

Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with my code or do I have to give functions permission to write to the cloud firestore database?

Answer (score 0):

You are not dealing with promises correctly.  Your function needs to return a promise that resolves with all of the asynchronous work is complete.  Right now, it's just returning null, and not waiting for any work to complete.

**All** Firestore operations are asynchronous and return a promise.  You will need to use these promises to build a single promise to return from the function.  That means each time you query and write a document, that's generating another promise to handle.

Also, you should know that there is no method `create()` that you're trying to use to add a document.  Perhaps you meant to use `set()` instead. The code will crash if it tries to execute `create()`.